# Why doesn't my ack --ignore-dir work?

Tags: search, ack

I'm trying to search my entire server for a string, whilst excluding dev/ (-R) using ack. So far I have

```
sudo ack -i --ignore-dir=dev * foo

--version ack v1.39
```

But I'm getting an error. Where am I going wrong?

Any help or advice on this matter is welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, whenever you say "I'm getting an error", change that to "I am getting the following error" and then tell us what the error is.  The error is important for us to be able to help diagnose the problem.

Second, the version of ack you're using is very old.  The latest is 1.96.

Third, you have your arguments out of order.  You're searching for "foo", right?  Then you should be doing "ack foo *", not "ack * foo".

You shouldn't be specifying "*" for a filename.  Let ack do the file finding for you.  If "dev" is a directory in the directory you're calling from, then "ack *" will expand to "ack dev [other directories]", which is explicitly telling ack to search in the "dev" directory, which overrides the `--ignore-dir` directive.

What you should be doing is:

```
ack -i --ignore-dir=dev foo
```

And then you let ack do the file finding.  You should only specify filenames on the command line if for some reason you have to override the files that `ack` is finding.

Finally, you probably shouldn't even be using ack for this task in the first place.  ack is specifically for searching source code, and it won't search files that it doesn't consider source code.  If you are searching the entire server, then you probably want to be searching non-source code files, too, right?  Use grep for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Worked perfectly

Comment: When you say "perfectly", are you sure?  Are ALL the files that you thought would be searched some kind of source code that ack recognizes?  For instance, ack does not search .cfg or .txt files, or files without extensions.  It *only* searches files of a type of source code that it recognizes.  When you say "my entire server" it doesn't sound like you only want to search source code.

Comment: the use-case is a little complicated. Basically, an old sysadmin went rogue and I, a web dev, am doing a search through the server to double check all files with their name in. This is just in case theres something nasty that I am unaware of already (after userdel, ssh revoke etc) I tried it with grep before but it seemed that it was a bit too over-the-top for the job...The searches are running away nicely and seem to be doing the job. Side Note. Most projects are in Rails. Cheers again